# Localize / Internationalize Static & Dynamic Content, Client Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, localization

Been trying to figure out a solution to internationalize a shopify store. Would really like to use JS or jQuery and switch languages instantly/client side without a reload using JSON-files for storing all language snippets..

There are a couple of really smart options (like localizejs.com), but they are rather expensive over time. Ideally we do not even need a super fancy backend and wouldn't mind "just" editing the language-files manually.

JSON could look like this:

```
{
    "english": {
        "Cart":"Warenkorb",
        "Products":"Produkte",
        "Contact":"Contact"
}
```

We appreciate any solution you can recommend! We need to be able to replace strings that contain elements like "href" as well though:

```
<div class="lang“>Replace <a href="#“>a Link</a></div>
```

How is this tackled usually?

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays people are trying [jQueryi18n](https://plugins.jquery.com/i18n/) plugin. May be you can check whether it can suffice your requirements. Its minified version size is upto 5KB. Its very easy to use in your project.

Comment: Thanks, that looks pretty simple to implement. Still not sure how to tackle entire html strings though…!

Comment: The problem being the languages syntax. A string like the above containing elements like href can be segmented, but might need to be rearranged in a different order…

Comment: I don't think it is possible to change the href value during document rendering as it expects string and not a variable. But you can change it through javascript by selecting the required element.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.SiteTran.com/ will enable you to switch languages on the client side, and it's free. It also can provide usable SEO urls (for your HREF's) and it only requires a snippet of javascript for integration.

If you want to do it on your own, you can just simply a JSON file with all of the translations and then with javascript load the text based upon the language.